# I want to send wattsapp message through my app , without opening wattsapp

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I saw so many tutorials on StackOverflow and also on other websites

But I can only find tutorials to send messages via WhatsApp itself,
So it opens WhatsApp,

I want to send a message without opening WhatsApp and purely through my App.

Comment: Hi, We need a bit more information before we can help you, are there methods you have tried? We need to see some code of what you have tried, Also you can check if there is a library somewhere that can help you with the issue

Comment: I want to send a message to a specific person without opening WhatsApp.I see some code on StackOverflow but I cannot understand it and also I see accessibility API. I need some help to achieve this task.

Answer (score 2):

Since Whatsapp is not a system app it is not possible to do so. In Message sending app there are APIs available from OS level. By using those APIs it is possible. Whatsapp is a third party app there is no API available to do. For this you only have explicit way to do so.

Comment: I see an application in play store that work with the same functionality as I want.The application name of that is Automate , Link of playstore is , https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitspice.automate , I want the same..

Comment: @Afaaq can you post link?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitspice.automate

Comment: @AfaaqAhmed Yes There are Apps that do this but its not officialy supported by whatsapp to do this (according to their FAQ), I would suggest not using unsupported methods like that as it can cause errors and issues in the future

Comment: It's supporting so that there are many apps available in play store, I want this functionality, please help me to do so. Its a project of me at my university.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this task through Assibility APIs.

Comment: Can you please guide me for this further, Its very important for me

Answer (score 0):

According to whatsapp themselves this is not possible wihtour unsupported workarounds
You will have to open whatsapp to send,

[Check The Whatsapp FAQ and developer guides](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/im-an-android-developer-how-can-i-integrate-whatsapp-with-my-app)